# how to make a bootstrap + vf page responsive?

Tags: visualforce, bootstrap

i was not able to create responsive tables using bootstrap in salesforce1                         app.Please help me if i have to make any changes to the code provided.
Thanks in advance.

```
<apex:page controller="Contactdynamicfiltercontroller" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" docType="html-5.0">
    <apex:form >
    <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css"/>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <apex:selectList value="{!Limitdynamic}" size="1">
            <apex:selectoptions value="{!values}"/>
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!displayRecords}" reRender="contab"/>
        </apex:selectList>

        <!----- Contact Record Table ------>
        <apex:outputPanel id="contab">
        <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <apex:repeat value="{!condetails}" var="c">
                    <tr>
                        <td>{!c.name}</td>
                        <td>{!c.phone}</td>
                        <td>{!c.email}</td>
                         <td>{!c.firstname}</td>
                        <td>{!c.lastname}</td>
                        <td>{!c.mobilephone}</td>
                        <td>{!c.accountid}</td>
                        <td>{!c.firstname}</td>
                        <td>{!c.lastname}</td>
                        <td>{!c.mobilephone}</td>
                        <td>{!c.accountid}</td>
                    </tr>
                </apex:repeat>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>

        </apex:outputPanel>
    </div>
    </body>    
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Can you provide screenshot as well? how it looks, we can able to help faster.

Comment: You didn't applied any bootstrap classes for small devices..(for responsive).

Comment: What dod you mean by 'i was not able to' ? What were you expecting  ? Based on what ? What was the result ?  Please provide more details, stating you failed doing something is not exactly asking us a question or providing information we can use to help.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly your table looks to be operating responsively.
You are getting a table small as possible within a window, than is horizontally scrollable.

There are many ways to consider something responsive.
Further down is an example of something simple and easy to read.

But first think about what you want to be responsive and what is in the table/your data.
Tables are not normally that responsive, especially ones of the size you are demonstrating.

Bootstrap is "Mobile first", and the table you have demo'd would struggle to fit on a mobile screen.

But lets say it does fit...
What part of the table do you want responsive? Table Width Table height cell width cell Height, or do you want columns to disappear or data to be truncated.

Here I demonstrate without bootstrap with just simple widths:
bootstrap is overkill, but it may fit with your existing design patterns.

```
<body>    
    <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <colgroup>
          <col style="width: 9%;"/> <col style="width: 9%;"/>
          <col style="width: 9%;"/> <col style="width: 9%;"/>
          <col style="width: 9%;"/> <col style="width: 9%;"/>
          <col style="width: 9%;"/> <col style="width: 9%;"/>
          <col style="width: 9%;"/> <col style="width: 9%;"/>
          <col style="width: 9%;"/>
      </colgroup>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>x</th>
                    <th>y</th>
                    <th>z</th>
                    <th>a</th>
                    <th>c</th>
                    <th>d</th>
                    <th>f</th>
                    <th>g</th>
                </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{!c.name}</td>
                        <td>{!c.phone}</td>
                        <td>{!c.email}</td>
                         <td>{!c.firstname}</td>
                        <td>{!c.lastname}</td>
                        <td>{!c.mobilephone}</td>
                        <td>{!c.accountid}</td>
                        <td>{!c.firstname}</td>
                        <td>{!c.lastname}</td>
                        <td>{!c.mobilephone}</td>
                        <td>{!c.accountid}</td>
                    </tr>
        </table>
</body>
```

I prefer to use grid system in bootstrap